# AngularJS controllers communication

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm not sure I'm doing what I need in the right way... I have 2 controllers:

**SiteMenuCntl** and **DashboardCntl**

SiteMenuCntl is bound to a UL tag, and it's the menu of the site. By default it's hidden, and after credentials verification and the DashboardCntl is loaded the menu should come visibile.

I tried this:

```
app.controller('SiteMenuCntl', ['$scope', 'site', 'security', '$log', function ($scope, site, security, $log) {
    $scope.visibility = "hidden";
    $scope.$on('showTree', function () {
        console.log("event fired"); //never fired :-(
        $scope.visibility = "";
    });
}]);

app.controller('DashboardCntl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$emit('showTree');
}]);
```

but the event showTree is never fired. Where am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your `SiteMenuCntl` is down the scope tree from the `DashboardCntl` so when `$emit` triggers upwards (towards `$rootScope`), it doesn't reach `SiteMenuCntl`.

Try using `$rootScope.$broadcast('showTree')` instead.  That triggers from the top of the tree downwards through any listening scopes.

- [$emit documenation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24emit)
- [$broadcast documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24broadcast)

Answer (score 0):

there's a way easier way to do this;

why don't you set a boolean `$scope.showSiteMenuCntl=false;` in your controller and then when you want to show it you go `$scope.showSiteMenuCntl=true;`

and then in your html you go;

```
<ul ng-controller="SiteMenuCntl" ng-show="showSiteMenuCtrl"></ul>
```

Comment: because showSiteMenuCtrl has to be set by DashboardCntl (when it's loaded) not by SiteMenuCntl.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I guess I didn't read the entire question, it is a suggestion though

Comment: yep, I'll use ng-show instead of controlling a css class, thanks.